# viewing document instead of downloading

Tags: html

I am using this code:

```
<div class="file">
  <a href="text.docx" download>
    <i class="fa fa-download">&nbsp;&nbsp;Download</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

This downloads the text.docx on clicking the link. What I want is, to view(only) this document instead of downloading it, like in google drive we view the document before downloading it.

**Update:** I have removed the `download` attribute, but it's still not working:

```
<div class="file">
  <a href="text.docx">
    <i class="fa fa-download">&nbsp;&nbsp;Download</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `download` attribute from the link?

Comment: what should i use instead?

Comment: Most browsers won't natively be able to display DOCX files. Google Drive uses an entirely custom developed in-browser replica of Word (more or less) (Google Docs) to do so…

Comment: you mean to say, i should use any other format?

Comment: i dont think so, that your browser can read only an docx without downloading it. but your browser should be able to read only .pdf files..

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), the `download` attribute on an `<a>` element:

> [...] instructs browsers to download a URL instead of navigating to it, so the user will be prompted to save it as a local file.

If you instead want to navigate to the link rather than download it, simply remove that attribute:

```
<a href="text.docx">
```

Note that it's still up to the server and the browser to actually negotiate that content.  If the server returns headers instructing the browser to treat the content as a file, that has nothing to do with your HTML.  Or if the browser has no way to display that content and defaults to treating it as a file, that's entirely in the browser and has nothing to do with your HTML.

But at the moment your `<a>` is *explicitly* telling the browser to download the file.  If you want to stop doing that, simply remove that attribute.

Comment: @Aditya_kr: You'll need to be more specific about the problem.  Have you modified the code as suggested?  What is the exact behavior now?  When the request for the file is made, what headers are in the server's response?  How have you set the browser to handle files of that type?

Comment: yes, i  want the browser to open the file instead of downloading or saving to your system, but <a href="text.docx"> prompts me to save the file.

Comment: @Aditya_kr: When the request for the file is made, what headers are in the server's response? How have you set the browser to handle files of that type?  These questions are *important* for you to answer and understand.  "I want it to just work" isn't programming.  Finding specific technical information and responding accordingly is.

Comment: <"I want it to just work" isn't programming> its not the way you think, i had my file on the server and server allows to view the file.

Comment: @Aditya_kr: `"server allows to view the the file"` - What do you mean by that?  There may be some program installed on the server which can, *on the server*, open and view the file.  But that doesn't mean anything to the web browser on the client.  Is the browser able to open files of that type anywhere else?  Are you able to directly open such a file in the browser at all?  If the web browser can't read that file type, then it's not going to display the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Google Docs Viewer`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="file">
  <a href="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/path/to/text.docx">
    <i class="fa fa-eye">&nbsp;&nbsp;View</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: means i have to upload files to google drive, then use the link here?

Comment: No, you can have your files on your server. You just need to provide the full filepath (including your domain name) after `?url=` part.

Answer (score 0):

By default most browser won't load .docx file. You might have to use .pdf files to view the document instead of downloading it.

NB: If you want to view .docx on the browser then you have to extract the contents of .docx, and display it in Html Page.